# Getting "error: invalid initializer" when calling bsearch

Tags: c, arrays, bsearch

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct DATA {
    char *key;
    char *parentKey;
    char *description;
} DATA;
```

And an array of instances:

```
DATA *data_array = NULL; // the global data array
int m_arrayLength = 0; // Keeps track of the number of elements used
```

Once the array is populated I am sorting it using `qsort`

```
void SortData()
{
    qsort(data_array, m_arrayLength, sizeof(DATA), CompareDataByKey);
}

int CompareDataByKey(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    DATA *ia = (DATA *)a;
    DATA *ib = (DATA *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->key, ib->key);
}
```

And this is working as expected. I'm trying to implement a method that searches the array for a particular item and this is where I am stuck

```
DATA FindDataByKey(char *key)
{
    DATA *searchData = malloc(sizeof(DATA));

    searchData->key = key;

    DATA result = bsearch(
        searchData, 
        data_array, 
        m_arrayLength, 
        sizeof(DATA), 
        CompareDataByKey);

    free(searchData);

    return result;
}
```

The `gcc` compiler is returning the message:

> p_CONNECT.c: In function 'FindDataByKey':
>
> p_CONNECT.c:87: error: invalid initializer
>
> make: The error code from the last command is 1.

on line `CompareDataByKey);`

Can anyone explain the meaning of this error in the context of the code I have written?

Comment: what is signature of "bsearch" function look like? Should address of method be passed? I gues that should be &CompareDataByKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thrown off by the line number reported by the compiler. The "incorrect initializer" message refers to the whole `DATA result = bsearch(...)` initialization/expression, which **ends** with the last argument, and not to the last argument itself.

Initializer is incorrect because `result` is declared as `DATA` (a struct), and `bsearch` returns a pointer. To fix it, declare `result` as a pointer:

```
DATA *result = bsearch(
        searchData, 
        data_array, 
        m_arrayLength, 
        sizeof(DATA), 
        CompareDataByKey);
```

When you fix that, you must also change `FindDataByKey` to return `DATA *`, not `DATA`. Several unrelated coding remarks:

- You don't need to `malloc` the search data when calling `bsearch`, you can just initialize it on the stack and pass the address of the variable to the function.  For example:

  ```
  DATA searchData;
  searchData.key = key;
  return bsearch(&searchData, ...);
  ```
- If you call `malloc`, don't forget to check its return value. A call to `malloc` can fail, and it is a good idea to report this failure to the user. (The customary way of doing that is by creating a wrapper called something like `xmalloc`, which calls `malloc`, checks its result, and prints an error message and calls `exit()` if the result is NULL.)
- Prefixing a global variable with `m_` will confuse users coming from a C++ background, where the `m_` prefix denotes class members.

Comment: The `malloc` was added in my struggle to resolve the problem and so has been removed. Should we use `g_` instead of `m_`?

Comment: @qujck There is no single convention. A lot of C code distinguishes between global and local names simply by global ones being long and descriptive (e.g. `common_data_array` or whatnot) and local ones being short (`array` or `arr`). Whatever you choose, just avoid `m_`, which is a well-established convention with a different meaning in C++.